# C# MySQL/MariaDB access BLOBs by streaming?

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb, blob

I am working on a table that has a LONGBLOB column and I need to SELECT/INSERT data.

At the moment the code to upload a file to the DB is the following:

```cs
using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO files(name, uploader, bin) VALUES (@fileName, @uploader, @bin)";
    using (command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uploader", "John Doe");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bin", File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the file is loaded as a whole in RAM, is there a way to stream data instead?

The code works, is just a matter of understanding if can be optimized

P.S. I am aware that storing big files directly into the database is bad practice, but this is legacy stuff.

Comment: You may want to specify why streaming would be better ... i.e., how long does this process take as-is, and what do you hope to gain, in terms of time, by streaming?

Comment: [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/load-data-local-infile/) might be one way but take note that it requires both a server setting [infile_local=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#local_infile) and `AllowLoadLocalInfile=true` in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a JPG that will be rendered in a web page, it is better to have it in a file on the server, then put the URL of that file in the database.  When the page is rendered, it will fetch multiple images asynchronously -- making the page load seem faster to the end-user.  And it avoids the need for discussing your Question.

If the BLOB is something else, please describe it and its usage.

It may be better to chunk it into multiple pieces, especially on a busy system that includes Replication.